# Java JSONObject.getJSONArray always returns null

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I want to use the Google Distance Matrix API to get the duration needed to travel between two locations. But when I try to get the duration from the returned data (JSON encoded) the method getJSONArray always returns null.

Here is the data sent by Google:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Rome, Metropolitan City of Rome, Italy" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Berlin, Germany" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,501 km",
                  "value" : 1501458
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 hours 5 mins",
                  "value" : 54291
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

And here is the method to get the duration:

```
public static int getDurationFromJSON(String json){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json)
                .getJSONArray("rows")
                .getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONArray ("elements")
                .getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("duration");

        return (int)(jsonObj.getInt("value") / 60.0f + 0.5f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

getJSONArray("rows") returns null.

Comment: Do you check the data received from Google API. What the content of json variable ?

Comment: The data of the json variable is the posted json code. It is exactly the same as the one I get when I start the request in the browser.

Comment: But are you sure you are getting the same content into the variable "json" when debugging the code ?

Comment: I am 100% sure.

Comment: I suggest you tu use a debugger to see what's in your jsonObj variable. If the function returns null it means that there is nothing, or that it's not the expected type, if you say that your are sure about the content, then you request the wrong type.

Comment: The debugger is useless at this point. It just says that there are no fields to display but the Object itself is not null. So getJSONArray can be called without throwing a NullPointerException. But there is also no exception thrown while parsing the string and also there are no errors in the string. I checked it 7 times.

Comment: Instead of parsing it manually, I would like to suggest you to create modal class of response you are getting from the google

Comment: But that's the same problem. In this class, I also have to parse the json data to get duration. It doesn't matter whether I create an extra class for it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here the solution. Don't trust org.json.* Use Gson:

Json-Data:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Rome, Metropolitan City of Rome, Italy" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Berlin, Germany" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,501 km",
                  "value" : 1501458
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 hours 5 mins",
                  "value" : 54291
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Create Object for Result:

```
public class DirectionMatrixResult {
    private String[] destination_addresses;
    private String[] origin_addresses;

    private DirectionMatrixResultRow[] rows;

    public DirectionMatrixResultRow[] getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public String[] getDestination_addresses() {
        return destination_addresses;
    }

    public String[] getOrigin_addresses() {
        return origin_addresses;
    }

    public void setDestination_addresses(String[] destination_addresses) {
        this.destination_addresses = destination_addresses;
    }

    public void setOrigin_addresses(String[] origin_addresses) {
        this.origin_addresses = origin_addresses;
    }

    public void setRows(DirectionMatrixResultRow[] rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }
}

public class DirectionMatrixResultRow {
    private DirectionMatrixResultElement[] elements;

    public DirectionMatrixResultElement[] getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(DirectionMatrixResultElement[] elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}

public class DirectionMatrixResultElement {
    private DirectionMatrixResultElementValue distance;
    private DirectionMatrixResultElementValue duration;
    private String status;

    public DirectionMatrixResultElementValue getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public DirectionMatrixResultElementValue getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setDistance(DirectionMatrixResultElementValue distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public void setDuration(DirectionMatrixResultElementValue duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

public class DirectionMatrixResultElementValue {
    private String text;
    private long value;

    public long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setValue(long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
public static int getDurationFromJSON(String json){
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        DirectionMatrixResult result = gson.fromJson(json, DirectionMatrixResult.class);
        return (int)(result.getRows()[0].getElements()[0].getDuration().getValue() / 60.0f + 0.0f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are getting the null, but this line seems excessive:

```
(int)(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(jsonObj.getInt("value"))) / 60.0f + 0.5f);
```

JsonObj.getInt("Value) is going to return an int, why are you turning this into a string, only to then parse it back into an Int and then casting that back into an INT again?

This could be simplified into simply like this

```
 return(int)((jsonObj.getInt("value")/60.0f) +0.5f)
```

As to the null, I would use a debugger and check the JSON being passed in and make sure it is what you think it is.

Also, as other have suggested, using something like restTemplate to auto parse the json into native mapped objects will make your life easier.

Comment: Actually, the line you mentioned is a leftover from a version where I got the duration as a string. Now it does not make any sense.